# Who is in charge of the Resolute?

Tags: plot-explanation, lost-in-space-2018

Watching Lost in Space (season 2) I’m confused about who is in overall charge. There’s the captain of the ship, the head of security and (if I remember correctly) the leader of the colonists.

At the point where I am the last of these is on the surface of a planet at risk of being left behind. They have cleansed their water in the atmosphere of a nearby planet and the head of security, for ulterior motives, tells the bridge they have enough clean water and it’s time to leave. Surely a) that’s not his decision to make and b) if he were just passing on a recommendation (which wasn’t his tone), it’s not his area of expertise, so should be queried.

I know the real answer is “dramatic drive”, but is the chain of command identified anywhere? I tried googling it but saw nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** The captain is in charge, but he is incapacitated, so leadership is a bit in shambles.

As far as depicted in the show, the captain would have absolute authority and you'd have a person worthy of command in charge. Such a person was actually in charge, this was captain Radic, but he was poisoned by Dr. Smith early in season 1. He is replaced by captain Kamal who obviously still struggles with absolute command in crisis situations.

Aside from the captain you have a few leaders also, most importantly:

- Victor Dhar: leader of the colonists. While a leadership position, in effect he still is there only for the single journey, this would make his authority lower than the permanent crew of the Resolute.
- Hastings: Intelligence officer, but during the show more 'head of security'. He clearly has loose morals and does not hesistate to blackmail/threaten people to get what he wants.
- Ben Adler: Director of advanced systems, basically in charge of scarecrow, important position.

And then of course there are the Robinsons, who despite not officially being in charge, constantly try to manipulate other people to follow their lead (of course, since they're the heroes, that would be the correct action ;)).

So you have an absolute chain of command, but because the top is still getting used to her power, these other authority figures have it easier to get their way, and it evolves more into a power-grab between them.

For the scene you are talking about, Hastings was initially convincing captain Kamal to abandon the stranded people because they did not have enough resources for the journey home. She (i.e. the captain) agreed to this.